# Framework7 Side Panels not working

Tags: css, html, html-framework-7

I'm developing an app mainly in HTML5/CSS/JS and I'm using framework7. Following the tutorials and all the documentation available I can't make a side panel appear... What am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
    <div class="panel-overlay">
        <div class="panel panel-left panel-reveal">
            <div class="content-block">
                <p>Menu de Opções</p>
                <p><a href="#" class="close-panel">Fechar Menu</a></p>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="views">
        <div class="view view-main">
            <div class="pages">
                <div data-page="home" class="page navbar-fixed">
                    <div class="navbar">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <div class="left">
                                <a href="#" class="link icon-only open-panel" data-panel="left">
                                    <i class="icon icon-bars"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="center">Home</div>
                            <div class="right"> <a href="#" class="link icon-only"> 
                                    <i class="icon icon-back"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="page-content">
                        <div class="content-block">
                            <p><a href="#" class="open-panel">Menu</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm testing on Chrome, but nothing is happening... It is also not working on IE

Comment: Read docs: https://framework7.io/docs/side-panels.html. Copy example, do not forget add JS.

Comment: @LeszekRepie i've already done that... I'll try once again... I'll post the feedback

Comment: @LeszekRepie It's working... I've forgotten to add the JS! Thanks a lot mate.